# Are there chiral fermions in $d=4$ Euclidean space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, chirality

In $d=4$ Euclidean space the spin group is $\operatorname{Spin}(4)\cong SU(2)\times SU(2)$ where the two $SU(2)$’s are independent (as opposed to Lorentzian signature where they conjugate into each other $\operatorname{Spin}(3,1)\cong SU(2)\times SU(2)^*$).

This means that say the conjugate of a left handed spinor $\psi$ is still left handed and implies that one can’t write a kinetic term for a single free Weyl fermion in $d=4$. Concretely for a kinetic term we need something like
\begin{equation}
\psi_R^\dagger \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_L
\end{equation}
Here we can observe the following: If we have a single left handed Weyl $\psi_L$, it’s conjugate $\psi_L^\dagger$ is still left handed and we can’t write a term like $\psi_L^\dagger \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_L $. Does this mean we can’t write chiral theories in $d=4$ Euclidean space? Am I just missing something to do with having to complexify $\operatorname{Spin}(4)$?

Comment: "And it is easy to see that such a term can’t be written for a single Weyl fermion in Euclidean signature." Maybe the question would be improved if you show your argument for this? There are chiral fermions in $d=4$ Euclidean space, but I don't understand your concern.

Comment: @octonion Thanks for your comment! I edited the question and I’m just concerned that we can’t conjugate a LH spinor to get a RH spinor but we need both to write a kinetic term.

Comment: It took me a little bit to understand what you mean but I think it's a good question and I upvoted. Using straightforward Wick rotation we can define $\sigma_E^\mu$ as $(i, \vec{\sigma})$, and $SO(4)$ transformations of the coordinate $\mu$ in $\sigma_E^\mu$ can be written in terms of a $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ transformation like $U_L \sigma_E^\mu U_R$. But $U_L$ and $U_R$ need not be related to each other, in contrast to the Minkowski case where $Spin(3,1)\sim SL(2,C)$. I think that is equivalent to the issue you are raising, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @octonion Thanks very much for your nice comment. Yes exactly that’s the issue I don’t understand!